# Azure Kusto time series

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

We are having some trouble using the time charts in Azure Kusto.
In this chart we have grouped http exceptions over time.

The issue is that the chart still reports the last seen value for points in time where that exception does not exist.
See red markings.
In this specific case we see that the chart reports 3.23k exceptions on the /poll endpoint at 5:28. while there are in fact no such error at that time.

[image]

The query looks like this

```
AppServiceHTTPLogs
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| where ScStatus >= 500
| summarize count() by tostring(CsUriStem), bin(TimeGenerated, 30m)
| render timechart
```

Using a column chart makes the issue go away, but this comes with the price of being much less clear.
Are there any other options?

Can we somehow make missing values default to 0 instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to fill with default zeros using make-series operator:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator

```
AppServiceHTTPLogs
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| where ScStatus >= 500
| make-series count() on TimeGenerated from ago(1d) to now() step 30min by tostring(CsUriStem)
| render timechart
```

Some UX clients do not know how to represent series data - and in this case you can expand it using mv-expand:

```
AppServiceHTTPLogs
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| where ScStatus >= 500
| make-series count() on TimeGenerated from ago(1d) to now() step 30min by tostring(CsUriStem)
| mv-expand count_ to typeof(long)
| render timechart
```

Comment: I really dislike this answer. Everyone uses summarize .. by bin to do aggregation. This makes me learn a completely different syntax when I just want to fill in zeros on summarize. Kusto should fix this with an addition to summarize .. by bin that in-fills zeros.